# Difference LESS and SASS/SCSS using &> as a base selector

Tags: css, sass, less

I am actually working on a LESS to SCSS converter. Actually I never really used LESS in depth but SCSS. Triggering done the basic differences and testing I come to a a few reg-ex replacements. 
Anyway there a syntax construct that I could not trigger down. In LESS you could write this :

```
.no-border &>table, 
.no-border .table-wrapper table {
   border:none !important;
}
```

anyway just compiling to :

```
.no-border > table,
.no-border .table-wrapper table {
  border: none !important;
}
```

(and so basically only stripping the &-parent operator ?)

Anyway SASS/SCSS does not allow this construct. And to be honest there is no sense for a selector which literal means "same parent but direct child" or do I miss something here ?

Maybe somebody how ever used this in LESS could explain for what the construct is useful for ?

In my converter I just replaced "&>" with a (plain) ">". Is this fine ?

Answer (score 1):

### Context here is Everything

I cannot say it is "fine" to replace it, as it depends upon the context it is found in. As a non-child, you are correct, it compiles to what you noted and your "solution" is fine. But if that code is in LESS and used (or imported) in the context of having parent selector(s), like this example:

```
.parent {
   .no-border &>table, 
   .no-border .table-wrapper table {
     border:none !important;
   } 
}
```

Then there is a major difference (and need) to keep it, as it produces this:

```
.no-border .parent > table,
.parent .no-border .table-wrapper table {
  border: none !important;
}
```

I would assume someone coded it the way they did to allow for this functionality of having the `.no-border` be either the parent of `.parent` or the child of `.parent`, probably for some specificity purposes (else one would think simply `.no-border table` would have worked).

At any rate, if you are dealing with a "converter" then I would think you would want to handle this conversion somehow to get the same output results in SCSS as LESS (else you end up with a "buggy" converter).